# user controlled groups or discussion script?

Tags: looking-for-a-script

Does any know of a Discussion or Groups script that allow users to create Groups and have members join those groups.

`PHP` written would be best

Answer (score 1):

- Cogear
- Drupal Commons
- Elgg

Answer (score 0):

There are many scripts out there that have the features you describe. It would be helpful is you can give more detail about the specific use cases (i.e. what problem are you trying to solve) and more details about things you have tried or have not tried.

Also, this type of open-ended question is not likely to generate a definitive answer and runs the risk of being closed: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask

Finally, [Buddypress](http://buddypress.org/).